# scrolled mouse coordinates not correct

Tags: c#, winforms

I am at a loss when trying to draw a rectangle on a panel which can be scrolled. The rectangles are drawn on a grid, so their start positions are rounded to the nearest 50px.
When drawing the rectangles their draw location is not correct relative to the grid lines after it has been scrolled.
However when the grid is scrolled after it has been drawn it does scroll with the panel.

I have tried to offset the coordinates of the mouse (I am using mouseDown, Move and Up events) but to no avail. Each rectangle is drawn at the mouse down, and then dragged right until release which finished the drawing (drawn and then size is increased with mouse move). Below are some a of the may things I have tired

```
Point screenPos = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
Point relLocation = grid.PointToClient(screenPos);

Point relLocation = e.Location;
relLocation.Offset(AutoScrollPosition);
```

[image]

Comment: When you scroll only a small portion of the window gets invalidated. The real question is if you hide the window and restore it again, is the window drawn correctly in that situation ? Btw we need more of your drawing logic.

Comment: You can also help yourself by positioning 2 textboxes on your form and simply store the value of your calculated x and y positions in relLocation, so you can visually check if they make sense.

Comment: I added a screenshot and will update with more information on the drawing logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the calculation that uses your grid and the scroll position in a mouse event:

```
   int grid = 50; 
   int x = e.X - (yourPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value / grid ) * grid ;
   currentPoint =  new Point((x / grid ) * grid , (e.Y / grid ) * grid );
```

Not sure how exactly you are drawing, as you haven't shown us the code, but this should do to find a position, that is currently on your grid..

I didn't include scrolling vertically, but you get the idea..

Comment: Thanks, I have mostly got it working (needs a few more unrelated tweaks). Like you suggested, `yourPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value` as what I was after, annoying how there isn't a built in function to do this!